# Error login to server with volley

Tags: android, eclipse, authentication, android-volley

I have problem with my login. Its force stop when the login button is click.

This is my code :

```
//Initializing views
    editTextEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edEmail);
    editTextPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edPassword);

    btlogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btlogin);
    btlogin.setOnClickListener(this);

    ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.btDaftar))
    .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


        public void onClick(View v) {
            LoginActivity.this.startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this,SignupActivity.class));
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    //In onresume fetching value from sharedpreference
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(Config.SHARED_PREF_NAME,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    //Fetching the boolean value form sharedpreferences
    loggedIn = sharedPreferences.getBoolean(Config.LOGGEDIN_SHARED_PREF, false);

    //If we will get true
    if(loggedIn){
        //We will start the Profile Activity
        Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}

private void login(){
    final String email = editTextEmail.getText().toString().trim();
    final String password = editTextPassword.getText().toString().trim();

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, Config.LOGIN_URL,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    if(response.trim().equalsIgnoreCase(Config.LOGIN_SUCCESS)){
                        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = LoginActivity.this.getSharedPreferences(Config.SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

                        editor.putBoolean(Config.LOGGEDIN_SHARED_PREF, true);
                        editor.putString(Config.EMAIL_SHARED_PREF, email);
                        editor.commit();

                        Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                        intent.putExtra("Exit me", true);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();

                    }else{

                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Invalid username or password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    }
            }){
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<>();
            //Adding parameters to request
            params.put(Config.KEY_EMAIL, email);
            params.put(Config.KEY_PASSWORD, password);

            //returning parameter
            return params;
        }
    };

    //Adding the string request to the queue
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    login();
}
```

the log cat is:

11-13 06:05:07.990: E/AndroidRuntime(13864): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-13 06:05:07.990: E/AndroidRuntime(13864): Process: com.example.mdesigntemp, PID: 13864
11-13 06:05:07.990: E/AndroidRuntime(13864): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.example.mdesigntemp.LoginActivity$4
11-13 06:05:07.990: E/AndroidRuntime(13864):    at com.example.mdesigntemp.LoginActivity.login(LoginActivity.java:84)
11-13 06:05:07.990: E/AndroidRuntime(13864):    at com.example.mdesigntemp.LoginActivity.onClick(LoginActivity.java:134)
11-13 06:05:07.990: E/AndroidRuntime(13864):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4783)
11-13 06:05:07.990: E/AndroidRuntime(13864):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19887)
11-13 06:05:07.990: E/AndroidRuntime(13864):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
11-13 06:05:07.990: E/AndroidRuntime(13864):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
11-13 06:05:07.990: E/AndroidRuntime(13864):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
11-13 06:05:07.990: E/AndroidRuntime(13864):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5290)
11-13 06:05:07.990: E/AndroidRuntime(13864):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
11-13 06:05:07.990: E/AndroidRuntime(13864):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
11-13 06:05:07.990: E/AndroidRuntime(13864):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:911)
11-13 06:05:07.990: E/AndroidRuntime(13864):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:706)

It says error in my

```
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, Config.LOGIN_URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
```

I don't know where is the fault. do i do a mistake? Every answer is helpful for me. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Update the code here:

```
(TextView)findViewById(R.id.btDaftar)
```

like:

```
TextView tx = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.btDaftar);
tx.setOnClickListener(this);
```

and override the onClick() method.